# Project Euler 15 - last attempt

Tags: haskell

During last three days I have been trying to solve [Project Euler 15](http://projecteuler.net/problem=15) in Haskell.

Here is my current state:

```
import Data.Map as Map

data Coord = Coord Int Int deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

corner :: Coord -> Bool 
corner (Coord x y) = (x == 0) && (y == 0)

side :: Coord -> Bool
side (Coord x y) = (x == 0) || (y == 0)

move_right :: Coord -> Coord
move_right (Coord x y) = Coord (x - 1) y

move_down :: Coord -> Coord
move_down (Coord x y) = Coord x (y - 1)

calculation :: Coord -> Integer
calculation coord 
           | corner coord = 0
           | side coord = 1 
           | otherwise = (calculation (move_right coord)) + (calculation (move_down coord)) 

problem_15 :: Int -> Integer
problem_15 size =
           calculation (Coord size size)
```

It works fine but it is very slow if the 'n' is getting bigger.

As I know I can use the dynamic programming and the hashtable (Data.Map, for example) to cache calculated values.

I was trying to [use memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410330/memoization-with-recursion), but don't have a success. I was trying [to use Data.Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428078/map-lookup-type-declaration-error), but each next error was more scary then previous.  So I ask your help: how to cache values which was already calculated ?

I know about mathematical solution of this problem (Pascal triangle), but I am interested in the algorithmic solution.

Comment: Use dynamic programming and a simple array. That way, the complexity is just quadratic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of a Map, this problem is better suited for an two-dimensional array cache, since we have a bounded range for input values.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Array

data Coord = Coord Int Int deriving (Show, Ord, Eq, Ix)

calculation :: Coord -> Integer
calculation coord@(Coord maxX maxY) = cache ! coord where
    cache = listArray bounds $ map calculate coords
    calculate coord
        | corner coord = 0
        | side coord   = 1
        | otherwise    = cache ! move_right coord + cache ! move_down coord

    zero  = Coord 0 0
    bounds = (zero, coord)
    coords = Coord <$> [0..maxX] <*> [0..maxY]
```

We add `deriving Ix` to Coord so we can use it directly as an array index and in calculation, we initialize a two-dimensional array `cache` with the lower bound of `Coord 0 0` and upper bound of `coord`. Then instead of recursively calling `calculation` we just refer to the values in the cache.

Now we can calculate even large values relatively quickly.

`*Main> problem_15 1000
2048151626989489714335162502980825044396424887981397033820382637671748186202083755828932994182610206201464766319998023692415481798004524792018047549769261578563012896634320647148511523952516512277685886115395462561479073786684641544445336176137700738556738145896300713065104559595144798887462063687185145518285511731662762536637730846829322553890497438594814317550307837964443708100851637248274627914170166198837648408435414308177859470377465651884755146807496946749238030331018187232980096685674585602525499101181135253534658887941966653674904511306110096311906270342502293155911108976733963991149120`

Comment: Thanks. What does it mean this syntax: coord@(Coord maxX maxY)

Comment: @demas It's an 'as-pattern', binding the entire value to `coord` and the parts (coordinates here) to the appropriate parts of the pattern in parentheses.

Comment: @shang: Won't the desired result be in `cache ! zero`? Isn't `cache ! coord` always `0`?

Comment: @gspr: Nope, it's the other way around. `cache ! zero == calculate (Coord 0 0) == 0`.

Comment: @shang: Oh right, my bad! I had my (mental) indexing opposite to yours.

Comment: try 100,000 and you will probably hit the recursion depth limit (as stack overflow exception or something).

Answer (score 6):

Since you already know the correct (efficient) solution, I'm not spoiling anything for you:

You can use an array (very appropriate here, since the domain is a rectangle)

```
import Data.Array

pathCounts :: Int -> Int -> Array (Int,Int) Integer
pathCounts height width = solution
  where
    solution =
        array ((0,0),(height-1,width-1)) [((i,j), count i j) | i <- [0 .. height-1]
                                                             , j <- [0 .. width-1]]
    count 0 j = 1  -- at the top, we can only come from the left
    count i 0 = 1  -- on the left edge, we can only come from above
    count i j = solution ! (i-1,j) + solution ! (i,j-1)
```

Or you can use the `State` monad (the previously calculated values are the state, stored in a `Map`):

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

type Path = State (Map Coord Integer)

calculation :: Coord -> Path Integer
calculation coord = do
    mb_count <- gets (Map.lookup coord)
    case mb_count of
      Just count -> return count
      Nothing
          | corner coord -> modify (Map.insert coord 0) >> return 0 -- should be 1, IMO
          | side coord -> modify (Map.insert coord 1) >> return 1
          | otherwise -> do
              above <- calculation (move_down coord)
              left <- calculation (move_right coord)
              let count = above + left
              modify (Map.insert coord count)
              return count
```

and run that with

```
evalState (calculation target) Map.empty
```

Or you can use one of the memoisation packages on hackage, off the top of my head I remember [data-memocombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators), but there are more, possibly some even better. (And there are still more possible ways of course.)

Comment: such array solutions suffer from deep recursion causing a stack overflow for very big argument numbers (doesn't apply for the original `20` of course). I tried once a sequence of `seq`s [threaded through the indices](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hofstadter_Q_sequence#Haskell) at some implementation-dependent step size. Is there other way perhaps?